# Problem with linked libraries and GTK+

Tags: c++, c, gtk

When trying to compile with Code::Blocks the example that comes up with GTK+:

```
#include stdlib.h
#include gtk/gtk.h

static void helloWorld (GtkWidget *wid, GtkWidget *win)
{
  GtkWidget *dialog = NULL;

  dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new (GTK_WINDOW (win), GTK_DIALOG_MODAL, GTK_MESSAGE_INFO, GTK_BUTTONS_CLOSE, "Hello World!");
  gtk_window_set_position (GTK_WINDOW (dialog), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_dialog_run (GTK_DIALOG (dialog));
  gtk_widget_destroy (dialog);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *button = NULL;
  GtkWidget *win = NULL;
  GtkWidget *vbox = NULL;

  /* Initialize GTK+ */
  g_log_set_handler ("Gtk", G_LOG_LEVEL_WARNING, (GLogFunc) gtk_false, NULL);
  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
  g_log_set_handler ("Gtk", G_LOG_LEVEL_WARNING, g_log_default_handler, NULL);

  /* Create the main window */
  win = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (win), 8);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (win), "Hello World");
  gtk_window_set_position (GTK_WINDOW (win), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_widget_realize (win);
  g_signal_connect (win, "destroy", gtk_main_quit, NULL);

  /* Create a vertical box with buttons */
  vbox = gtk_vbox_new (TRUE, 6);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (win), vbox);

  button = gtk_button_new_from_stock (GTK_STOCK_DIALOG_INFO);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (helloWorld), (gpointer) win);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), button, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

  button = gtk_button_new_from_stock (GTK_STOCK_CLOSE);
  g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", gtk_main_quit, NULL);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), button, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

  /* Enter the main loop */
  gtk_widget_show_all (win);
  gtk_main ();
  return 0;
}
```

I receive the following errors:

```
ld.exe||cannot find -lgobject-2.0|
ld.exe||cannot find -lglib-2.0|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

I have linked both to the project, but I can't find a way to make it work. I have tried both the bundled and separated packages from http://www.gtk.org/download-windows.html. I'm pretty sure it must be something simple/stupid but I couldn't find anything that could help me to solve this problem.

Comment: How are you building your code? What's the command you are using?

Comment: Even if I have somehow worked it out by now, where can I find the full build command in Code::Blocks?

Comment: may be use make file for compiling your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added the GTK Directory containing the libglib-2.0.a, libgobject-2.0.a files to the Linker Search Directories.
This can be done from the following Path:
**`Settings | Compiler and debugger... | Search directories | Linker | Add`**.

The full command line for the compiler/linker can be viewed in the `Build Log` window. To enable this go to:
**`Settings | Compiler and debugger... | Other Settings | Compiler logging | Full command line`**

I didn't come across the missing entrance point issue so maybe your copy of GTK is corrupted. Download the All-in-one bundle from [GTK+ 2.22](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/gtk+/2.22/gtk+-bundle_2.22.1-20101227_win32.zip)

make sure you add all the Include Directories in `Search directories | Compiler`

As a side note you may need to compile your project using `-mms-bitfields` which can be added in:
**`Settings | Compiler and debugger... | Other options`** just paste the flag as is.

Comment: That seems to have worked. But I don't understand why I need to put the directory when I include the full path to the lib on the linker itself? Furthermore, I'm having a new problem when running the finished executable and I'm not sure if it's related to this. "Can't find entrance point of the procedure g_bsearch_array_destroy in the libglib-2.0.0 dll." Thanks for the help edit: forgot to mention I included all the necessary dll's.

Comment: I've tried linking to the .libs from the blunded one, and used the included dll to no luck. Thanks for the help. I will try to find a way.

Answer (score 0):

When code::blocks is running ld.exe instead of calling it with, for example: `-l glib-2.0` it is calling it with `-lglib-2.0`

Adding a space before the lib's name in code::block's linker options should fix it.